# Special harmonic series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm able to show that the special harmonic series
$$
1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10} \cdots
$$
is convergent. What is its limit?

Comment: I have voted to close.  I might reverse that if you were to provide any kind of context or reason why there might be a meaningful answer.

Comment: Grouping terms as $\quad(1)-(1/2+1/3)+(1/4+1/5+1/6)-(1/7+1/8+1/9+1/10)+\cdots\quad$ gives an alternating series whose sum is $0.517\dots$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}
\sum_{n=k(k-1)/2+1}^{k(k+1)/2} \frac{1}{n}$$
that can be written as
$$ \gamma-4+8 \ln(2)- 2\,\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left( -1 \right) ^{k}\Psi \left( \frac{k(k+1)}{2}
 \right)  
$$
but I don't know a closed form for the last sum;  OEIS and Inverse Symbolic Calculator don't seem to help.